# An Error While Displaying the Winner in Swift (Xcode) in iOS game Development

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have set up the following winning conditions in my game :-

```
    var player1Score = ""

    var player1Name = ""

    var player2Score = ""
 
    var player2Name = ""

    if (player1Score > player2Score) {
        
        playerWinsLabel.text = "\(player1Name) YOU WIN!"
        
    }
    else if (player2Score > player1Score) {
        
        playerWinsLabel.text = "\(player2Name) YOU WIN!"
        
    }
    else {
        
        playerWinsLabel.text = "IT'S A TIE!"
        
    }
```

But, whenever player1Score reaches 100+ and player2Score is <100, the playerWinsLabel.text displays (player2 YOU WIN!). But, it should be showing (player1 YOU WIN!). Apart from this case it works fine. Could anyone please let me know what's wrong in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You deal with them as strings while you should make them integers

```
var player1Score = 0 
var player2Score = 0
```

below 100 may means 2...9 as the left most value which is higher than 1 for 100+ in strings comparison

Comment: I tried to use INT(player1Score) > INT(player2Score). But, it. was giving me an error!

Comment: you should originally make them integers that makes more sense but try  `Int(player1Score)!  > Int(player2Score)!`

Answer (score 1):

Don't store numbers as `String`.

When you compare strings using > and < it is a *lexical comparison* (Think about how you alphabetise a list of words).

For example, "Jane" comes before ("is less than") "John" because they both start with J but "a" is less than "o" and you don't need to look any further.  If player 1 has a score of "100" and player 2 has "90" then player 2 wins because "1" comes before (is less than) "9".

You should declare your score properties as `Int`:

```
var player1Score = 0
var player2Score = 0
```

Assigning 0 (an integer) to the properties implicitly declares them as `Int`.